# Local Storage/Session Storage/Cookies

Tags: angular, cookies, local-storage, session-storage

I want to save Phone number and mail ID in session storage/local storage in Angular. I have written code to collect details. But I have no idea regarding the next step.

```
    <h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID: [(ngModel)]</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mail ID" name="mail" required>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" required>

        <button (click)="myFunc()">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

//On click of button I have to save the information and move to the next page. When I come back, it should be available. Please help

My Typescript file is as follows:

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MyProductPageComponent } from '../my-product-page/my-product-page.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-home-page',
  templateUrl: './my-home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-home-page.component.css']
})

export class MyHomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  myFunc() {
    localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    localStorage.setItem("mail", mailID);
    this.router.navigate(['/products']);
  }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'MyProductPageComponent', component: MyProductPageComponent },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: What does `myFunc()` do or what do you think it should do? Some code sample of your work will be useful and check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage if you need

Comment: I want to fetch Phone number and Email from Form. And save it in an local storage.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do what you are asking. I'll follow your lead to keep the changes minimal but recommend reading up on how forms in Angular are developed.

Add template reference variables to the input elements, `#email` and `#phone`, so that their values can be used with the function associated with the click handler `(click)="saveForm(email.value, phone.value)"`. I renamed this from `myFunc()`. The stored email value is displayed with `{{mailID}}`.

```html
<h2>Welcome User!!!</h2>
<form class="container" action="/product">
    <div>
        <label for="mail"><b>Email-ID: {{mailID}}</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter mail ID" name="mail" required #email>
    <br>
        <label for="psw"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" name="phoneNumber" required #phone>

        <button (click)="saveForm(email.value, phone.value)">NEXT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Within the component class save the form with the provided email and phone values from the template click handler as seen in the `saveForm(email, phone)` method. After the form is saved and when the component is initialised, `getSavedForm()` is called to return the values from `localStorage` or set an empty string `''` if there are no saved values.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  phoneNumber: string;
  mailID: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSavedForm();
  }

  saveForm(email, phone) {
    localStorage.setItem("phoneNumber", phone);
    localStorage.setItem("mailID", email);
    this.getSavedForm();
  }

  getSavedForm() {
    this.phoneNumber = localStorage.getItem("phoneNumber") || '';
    this.mailID = localStorage.getItem("mailID") || '';
  }

}
```

Here is a working [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axr63t).

I strongly suggest digging into the forms capability of Angular if you are intending to do more as the current approach isn't exactly the most ideal. See [Introduction to forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) for more on using template driven or reactive forms.